# Solr multiple words search

Tags: solr

I have an indexed field name Keyword
I am setting the field as:

```xml
<field name="KeywordDescription" type="text_en_splitting" 
       indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

When I perform a search on keyword with data like:
luxury+2008

I would like to have all records that contains the words luxury and 2008 to be returned.
For example, the search should return records like:

1. 2008 luxury rooms
2. rooms with luxury furnishing available since 2008

Comment: This is very, very basic operation of Solr and is covered in every tutorial of the subject, including the examples bundled with Solr. If you're having any issues, you'll have to include the relevant portions of your schema.xml, how you're indexing and what you're querying from the index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the syntax for queries such as:

```
KeywordDescription:value1 AND KeywordDescription:value2
```

so:

```
KeywordDescription:luxury AND KeywordDescription:2008
```

Some links that might help you:

[Query syntax](http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html)

[Query syntax 2](http://www.solrtutorial.com/solr-query-syntax.html)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `df` [default field](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SearchHandler#df)  ,like this:

> df=KeywordDescription & q=luxury AND 2008